# Backspace not working when implementing shouldChangeCharactersInRange method - iPhone Dev

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Problem... I have a string of allowable characters "0123456789." How do I also allow the backspace from the keyboard... when I implement the code from below... the backspace key no longer works... How can I fix this?

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string { 

    NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet];

    return ([string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet].length > 0);

}
```

Comment: Here is the answer:

- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet];
 
 if (range.length == 1){
  return string;
 }else{
 return ([string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet].length > 0);
 }
 
 
}

Comment: took out structure... I'll answer it below.

Comment: return string; // doesn't make sense, not a boolean, should be return YES;

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet];

    if (range.length == 1){
        return YES;
    }else{
        return ([string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet].length > 0);
    }


}
```

Comment: I added if [string isEqualToString:@"\n"] return YES; to catch when the user presses done/return key.

Comment: Instead of `range.length == 1`, check `[string length] == 0`. Otherwise you can select a single character and replace it with a non-numerical character, and you can't delete or cut more than 1 character at once.

Comment: Instead of returning `[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet].length > 0`, set `textField.text` to the trimmed string and return `NO`. Otherwise you can paste a non-numerical character into the text field if the paste also contains a numerical character. (Though this is straying from the original issue of making backspace work.)

Answer (score 15):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if ([string length] == 0) 
        return YES; 

    NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet] invertedSet];
    string = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet] componentsJoinedByString:@""]; 
    textField.text = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]; 

    return NO; 
}
```

This should work correctly with deleting/cutting multiple characters at once, as well as pasting. Corrections welcome. The only known problem is that when you edit in the middle of the text field the cursor gets sent to the end (because it returns `NO`) -- I guess you have to [use a `UITextView` to fix that](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/239653-substituting-characters-in-uitextfield.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
NSCharacterSet *theNonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet];


        if (range.length == 1){
            return YES;
        }else if(textField.text.length < ZipcodeTextLength)
        {
            return ([string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:theNonNumberSet].length > 0);
        }
        else
            return NO;
```

> This will allow Numbers and Backspace and also you can limit the text length.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of my implementations. Maybe it works for you.

```
-(BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

for(UIView *view in _chooseUsernameDialog.subviews) {
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        int realLength;

        const char * _char = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        int isBackSpace = strcmp(_char, "\b");

        if (isBackSpace == -8) {
            // is backspace
            realLength = [textField.text length] - 1 ;
        }
        else
        {
            realLength = [textField.text length] + 1;
        }

        NSLog(@"%d", realLength );

        if(realLength < 4)
        {
            //too short

        }
        else{

            //long enough
        }
    }
}

return !([[textField text] length] + (string.length - range.length) > 13);
}
```